# Loading a panel from a different class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have two classes. The main class has a JFrame and holds a button, which after clicking the button, it loads a panel from a different class and locate it in the button of the frame.

I could achieve it, but I have to re-size the frame then the additional panel appears, otherwise it is hidden.

Here is my code:

```
public class PanelLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton press = new JButton("press");
        press.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //ActionListener, on click it opens a file choser, 
           @Override                                      //selects a directory then gives it to srcDirField
           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event){
                JPanel mine = ClassWhereStored.newJPanel();
                mainPanel.add(mine, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           }
        });

        mainPanel.add(press, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
public class ClassWhereStored {
    public static JPanel newJPanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JLabel test= new JLabel("Some Text");
        panel.add(test);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

So what is wrong with this frame that shows the additional panel only if I re-size the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout`, adding a blank/empty `JPanel` and the `JPanel` you want to display.  When the button is clicked, simply have the `CardLayout` switch the panels.

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

For example...

```
package javaapplication765;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new BasePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BasePane extends JPanel {

        public BasePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
            JPanel mainView = new JPanel(cl);
            mainView.add(new JPanel(), "empty");
            mainView.add(new BananaPane(), "banana");
            add(mainView);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Fruit loop");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cl.show(mainView, "banana");
                }
            });
            add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

    }

    public class BananaPane extends JPanel {

        public BananaPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25, 25, 25, 25));
            add(new JLabel("I'm a banana"));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid static methods if possible as this risks increasing coupling and reducing cohesion.
2. As for your problem, you're best using a CardLayout and adding your new JPanel to the CardLayout-using container, the JPanel held in the SOUTH, but hidden, say covered by a JLabel that is also added to the same CardLayout-using container and which is showing. This way the container (the southern JPanel that uses CardLayout) will be sized to accommodate all "cards" it contains, as long as the "card" components are added at gui creation time.